# Android Unit Test + DecimalFormat

Tags: android, unit-testing, decimalformat

I have a method that formats a number, and I wanted to test it.
I built a test calling this method and the result showed that: `decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(\* Any rounding mode \*);` 
doesn't work. It always takes the default `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`.

My method works fine - `decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);` do work when running the app (I copied the test to the app and logged it..)

Why can't I call `decimalFormat.setRoundingMode()` in a unit test?

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code. Replace the RoundingMode.HALF_UP value with its hard coded primitive value (the value behind it).The static call to RoundingMode  might be the cause of this. 
It also seems to me that your unit test is wrong, you're checking a behavior of a class based on an existing implementation of your dependency (decimalFormat). You should never do this in an unit test instead you have to mock decimalFormat away and test the behavior of your method independently from the implementation of 'decimalFormat' or any other dependency.